# applying solidifying modifier distorts object

Tags: modifiers

I am using the solifying modifier for the first time and following a tutorial but not sure why my object got distorted.
I tried many things including removing doubles, applying the scale (forgot to include this in the gif animation below).  Could you please have a look?

[image]

[image: blender screencast]

Comment: The [scale still isn't applied](http://imgur.com/3QrNZoY) fully, so that's first problem. Second - there are some flipped normals, use `Ctrl`+`N`.

Comment: I have already tried all those before. In fact, I displayed all my normals to make sure they face outwards. Nothing seems to work:(

Comment: Sure, thanks for your help - I have corrected for both and here is the file which still shows the distortion. [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=971" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/971/)